# How to uninstall git on Linux which is installed from source

Tags: linux, git, installation

I have installed git on RHEL-7 using below commands-

tar xzf git-2.0.1.tar.gz,
cd git-2.0.1,
make,
make install

Basically I wanted to upgrade version to 2.10 so how can I uninstall existing git?
What if I just delete the git-2.0.1 directory and follow same steps for new version?

Comment: You should have not installed it as root. However, it is not a programming question. For Linux-related non-programming questions, I suggest to visit https://unix.stackexchange.com.

Answer (score 3):

You don't need to uninstall it, you can just unpack new version, build it and install to the same place.

But in case you still need to uninstall it, you can run `make uninstall` (if folder with source code is still available) or just remove folder with git (run `which git`, it will show you installation folder, eg. `/use/local/bin` or `~/bin/`).

Comment: Thanks, `make uninstall` did not work.
 I extracted the new version(/opt/git-2.10/), installed with same commands and deleted the old source code folder(/opt/git-2.0.1). This worked, but is this the good way to directly delete the old folder?

Comment: You could remove your old **source** code even after the first installation, it was not needed after. You can now remove your new source folder.